# Where is the String from?

Tags: java, android

I am currently learning Programming for Android through Warescriptions Busy Coders Guide.

This code compiles and works fine. However I don't understand how exactly the content of the String is defined, and where Button is getting this String from. Any explanations appreciated.

```
public class FlipperDemo2 extends Activity {
static String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet",
                                                "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit",
                                                "morbi", "vel", "ligula", "vitae",
                                                "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis", "etiam",
                                                "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
                                                "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque",
                                                "augue", "purus"};
ViewFlipper flipper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    flipper=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.details);

    for (String item : items) {
        Button btn=new Button(this);

        btn.setText(item);

        flipper.addView(btn,
                                        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    }

    flipper.setFlipInterval(2000);
    flipper.startFlipping();
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static String[] items
```

`items` is an array of `String` objects.

```
for (String item : items) {
```

This is a for-each loop. Is says "For each (`String`) item in the (`String[]`) array items ..."

Comment: Thank you for the quick and easy to understand answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a array of strings where buttons get their values.

In onCreate method buttons are created in for each loop. This loop iterates over the list of strings and creates buttons which count is the count of the strings in the array. And buttons captions are the strings in the array.

Answer (score 0):

The text on the Button is defined in `btn.setText(item);` which it is pretty self-explanatory (it sets the text content to the `item` string).

Each `item` comes from looping through the `static String[]` array defined at the top.